# Is it possible to skip confirmation page in SagePay custom templates

Tags: opayo

I'm setting up a set of custom templates for a SagePay server integration (iFrame), and I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to prevent the confirmation page (card_confirmation.xslt) being presented to the user.

It mostly duplicates information presents to customers earlier on in the checkout process and so is largely redundant.

So it's a bit of a long shot but can we by modifying some form value in one of the other templates or by any other method tell the system to skip that page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get this confirmation page if you pass Profile=LOW with the original transaction registration post. In fact, if you are *not* sending this and displaying the Sage Pay screens in an iframe, you are going to have problems with some browsers.

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking so long to respond.  This does work as described, thanks.